# My node is not showing on Bitnodes

Tags: wallet, full-node, bitnodes

I have a 0.16.3 Bitcoin Core wallet running. I have incoming transactions allowed and I have lots of incoming connections. However, I fail to see my node on the map of [Bitnodes](https://bitnodes.earn.com/); it says it's unreachable, also I have tried to appoint it as a trusted node to my Samourai wallet, and Samourai also fails to connect to my node.

Comment: i dont understand, how is it reachable to you and how does it produce spam ?

Comment: @scaaahu How do you know if OP's node is reachable, as he hasn't given an IP address?

Comment: To the OP and @PieterWuille : My bad and my misunderstanding. I apologize. My spam flag was declined and I just upvoted this question to make it up. Sorry again.

Comment: The reason a running node shows as 'unreachable' on bitnodes.io is that (y)our "maxconnections" limit has been reached. Sometimes connections drop off and we can get lucky by repeat clicking on the "CHECK NODE" button. Restarting bitcoind increases the chances of getting a green banner as connections slowly build up to the maximum configured in 'bitcoin.conf'. I wish there was a whitelist that accepted incoming IP connections regardless of "maxconnections".

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, sometimes the router doesn't actually respond to the UPnP setting for mapping the listening port. What always seems to be working for me is

- Shutdown your node (`cli stop && shutdown`)
- Restart your router (usually unplug, wait a minute, replug and wait a few minutes)
- Restart node

Regarding the hookup to Samourai, what exactly are your `bitcoin.conf` settings?

Comment: so shuting down the node and restarting the router i've done many times already, however im on my way to change my router with a new one as this one is old anyway. Samourai requires IP of the node, RPC pass/user and port. as information in order to appoint your node as a trusted one to your samourai wallet.